# Having problem in creating new project in visual studio code 2019

Tags: visual-studio, c#-3.0

I have recently installed **Visual Studio 2019** in my Windows 10 laptop and installed the workload ** ".Net desktop development"** in it.

After installing it when i attempted to created a new project, I got the error message like this.

[[image]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzaQI.png)

Comment: What is the point of showing startup screen of VS? And put irrelevant tags

Comment: I don't see any errors!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: i am extremely sorry for attaching a wrong screen shot. This is my first question in Stack Overflow, so kindly excuse for the mistake i have committed. And thanks for your kind replies.

Comment: have you also installed the .net core workload?

Comment: No, I didn't installed the .net core workload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a .net core application

[image]

So you need to select the [cross platform .net core workload during setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-4---choose-workloads)

[image]

Comment: @NivethaS ok, in this case [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Comment: Thanks, I closed the question.